# how to access a member of a structure using a pointer offset

Tags: c

/* Trying to copy a value from member of one structure to another using pointers and structure offset: */

```
enter code here

typedef struct
{
    uint8 Value;
    uint8 Status;
} sts;

typedef struct
{
   sts CC1;
   sts CC2;
   sts CC3;
   sts CC4;
} StructTypeWrite;

typedef struct
{
   uint8 CC1;
   uint8 CC2;
   uint8 CC3;
   uint8 CC4;
} StructTypeRead;   

static StructTypeWrite WriteVariable;
static StructTypeRead ReadVariable;

void main(void)
{
    StructTypeWrite *WritePtr;
    StructTypeRead *ValPtr;
    uint8 i;

    /* Just Writing Value in order to check */
    WriteVariable.CC1.Value = 5;
    WriteVariable.CC2.Value = 30;   
    WriteVariable.CC3.Value = 40;   
    WriteVariable.CC4.Value = 45;

    WritePtr = &WriteVariable;
    ValPtr = &ReadVariable;

    for(i=0; i<4; i++) 
    {
        /* Need to copy all the members value to another structure */
        *((uint8*)ValPtr + i) = *((sts*)(uint8*)WritePtr + i)->Value;
    }
}
```

error during compilation is :
error #75: operand of "*" must be a pointer
            *((uint8*)ValPtr + i) = *((sts*)(uint8*)WritePtr + i)->Value;

Can anyone help me where am i wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correctly computing the pointer offsets. However, you are dereferencing too many times. The arrow notation `->` dereferences a struct in C. So if you are using `->`, you should not also be using `*`. I corrected your code by using only the arrow to dereference. Like so:

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++) 
{
    /* Need to copy all the members value to another structure */
    *((uint8*)ValPtr + i) = ((sts*)(uint8*)WritePtr + i)->Value;
}
```

Notice the star I removed right after the `=` on the assignment line.

Edit: You should not compute pointer offsets like this in a struct, because different struct elements will be padded differently. Use the `offsetof` macro instead.

Like so:

```
uint8* newCC1Address = WritePtr + offsetof(StructTypeWrite, CC1);
```

This will ensure that the offset is correctly computed given the potential for different byte offsets due to padding.

Comment: This is not the correct way to compute pointer offsets to members within a `struct`, since [there may be padding](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.2.1p15) within the `struct`. The correct method is to use the [`offsetof` macro](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19p3).

Answer (score 1):

Avoid accessing struct members using pointer offset.
The compiler may add padding bytes to get a proper alignment.
see [Data structure alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)
Why don't you use arrays instead of structs?
sts WriteVariable[4];
uint8 ReadVariable[4];

Comment: Yes you are right but it is as per the design. So cannot be changed.